# Purrr Multiply index data frame with dataframe

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Thank you all for reading this problem.
What i would like to do is multiply my testdata with my index file while matching columns.
So multiplying Dp_water with Dp_water and iterating over all index vars kcal, fat, prot, carbs.

In my test data i have for 10 individuals data on consumption of 4 food groups in grams.
for each individual i would like to calculate the kcal fat prot carb intake.
For each individual i would like to make a new variable
Dp_water_kcal, Dp_coffee_kcal, Dp_soup_kcal , Dp_soda_kcal
Dp_water_fat, Dp_coffee_fat, Dp_soup_fat , Dp_soda_fat
ect...

```
library(tidyverse)

Sample data

Index file
index <- data.frame(Variable=c("Dp_water","Dp_coffee","Dp_soup","Dp_soda"), 
                  kcal=c(0,10,20,40),
                  fat=c(0,5,10,15),
                  prot=c(2,4,6,8),
                  carbs=c(3,6,9,12))

index <-  index %>%
          pivot_longer(c(kcal,fat,prot,carbs)) %>%
          pivot_wider(names_from = Variable, values_from = value)
> index
# A tibble: 4 x 5
  name  Dp_water Dp_coffee Dp_soup Dp_soda
  <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1 kcal         0        10      20      40
2 fat          0         5      10      15
3 prot         2         4       6       8
4 carbs        3         6       9      12
```

Below subject data consumption of 4 foodgroups.

```
test_data <- data.frame(Dp_water=c(11:20),
                   Dp_coffee=c(31:40),
                   Dp_soup=c(21:30),
                   Dp_soda=c(41:50),
                   id=1:10)

   Dp_water Dp_coffee Dp_soup Dp_soda id
1        11        31      21      41  1
2        12        32      22      42  2
3        13        33      23      43  3
4        14        34      24      44  4
5        15        35      25      45  5
6        16        36      26      46  6
7        17        37      27      47  7
8        18        38      28      48  8
9        19        39      29      49  9
10       20        40      30      50 10
```

If i do the following it works. But i would like to do this for all variables and not only kcal. And i would like to be able to keep the id column.

```
test_data %>%
select(-id) %>%
map2_dfr(., test_data[match(names(.), names(test_data))], ~.x/100 * .y) %>%
set_names(paste0(names(.), "_kcal")) 

# A tibble: 10 x 4
   Dp_water_kcal Dp_coffee_kcal Dp_soup_kcal Dp_soda_kcal
           <dbl>          <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl>
 1          1.21           9.61         4.41         16.8
 2          1.44          10.2          4.84         17.6
 3          1.69          10.9          5.29         18.5
 4          1.96          11.6          5.76         19.4
 5          2.25          12.2          6.25         20.2
 6          2.56          13.0          6.76         21.2
 7          2.89          13.7          7.29         22.1
 8          3.24          14.4          7.84         23.0
 9          3.61          15.2          8.41         24.0
10          4             16            9            25
```

Thank you all for any help!

Comment: I couldn't understand the use of `index` data in this code?

Comment: see the second argument `test_data[match(names(.), names(test_data))]` is no different from your `test_data` without id column.  See `identical(test_data[match(names(test_data %>% select(-id)), names(test_data))], test_data %>% select(-id))` retursn `TRUE`.  So I am still unable to understand use of two same arguments in `map2` one as `.` and another as `test_data[match(names(.), names(test_data))]` ?? can you please clarify? and where does `kcal` comes in picture?

Comment: `test_data %>% select(-id) %>% map2_dfr(., ., ~.x/100 * .y) %>%  set_names(paste0(names(.), "_kcal"))` will also result in same output.  Please re-check and better if logic for transformation is explained directly!

Comment: even `test_data %>% select(-id) %>% map_dfr(., ~.x/100 * .x) %>%  set_names(paste0(names(.), "_kcal"))` this is also same

Comment: Can you show your final expected output for the data shared? I am not sure if I have understood your question correctly.